# Identification of a small to mid-sized, yellow moth species found in India at monsoon season

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera

[image: Yellow Indian moth]

I am from India and it's monsoon here. What is the name of this insect?

Description:

- Length: ~4cm
- Width: ~2.5cm
- Color: yellow, almost uniform across the wings. Slightly darker, dandelion yellow across the body.
- Small black dot in the middle of each large wing.
- White, speckled iridescence on wings.
- Short antennae.
- Longer than average hair for moths.

Comment: I am confused between *Porthesia Atereta* and *Yellow Tussock Moth*

Comment: This is likely a member of the Nygmiini moths. The Nygmiini are a tribe of tussock moths of the subfamily Lymantriinae (formerly called the Lymantriidae) of the Erebidae family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely a member of the Nygmiini moths. The [Nygmiini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nygmiini) are a tribe of tussock moths of the subfamily [Lymantriinae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lymantriinae) (formerly called the Lymantriidae) of the [Erebidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erebidae) family

A specimen that closely resembles yours can be seen [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/itchydogimages/15614599836/), and copied below:

[image]

I have not found a definitive species for you, but will keep looking. I'd advise you try to do the same given this information.